# How to stretch StackPanel to FullScreen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have ItemDetailPage.xaml with FlipView, inside of DataTemplate i have Grid with come columns. One of columns contains StackPanel with some controls.
Example:

```
<FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid Margin="120,0,20,20" x:Name="richTextColumns">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" x:Name="ContentPanel">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="22" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <Image x:Name="image" Width="200" Margin="0,10,0,10" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Image}"/>


                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <RichTextBlock x:Name="InformationOriginalName" Width="250" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding EvaInformation.OriginalName}"/>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </RichTextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                    ....

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

How to stretch **ContentPanel** to FullScreen and hide all different controls, including Back button and title of page?

Comment: As far as I know `StackPanel` can't stretch, why don't you use a `Grid` with several rows instead?

Comment: I have many elements like mmppf:MediaPlayer (media player framework).
so players creeps on each other

Comment: Use `Canvas` instead of `StackPanel` if you don't want to use `Grid` but want to stretch.

Comment: I remove StackPanels, but i can stretch element only inside Grid cell - isn't full screen

Comment: In this case use `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` attached properties to place an element across several `Grid` cells